# CoreAnimation - CABasicAnimation get value steps for 30-60 FPS animations

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, math, core-animation

I've got a CABasicAnimation that is operating on the transform property of a CALayer.
The animation looks fairly cool and it all works fine, but now I want to know through which values the transform of the layer is going to go through for a perfect 30/60 FPS animation.

I don't want to run the aniamtion and measure the values, I want to know beforehand.

The timingFunction has to be taken into account for this calculation.

How can I find out these transform values?

That's the animation code:

```
CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath: @"transform"];
animation.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D: _myLayer.transform];
animation.toValue   = valueTransform;
animation.duration  = 0.7;
animation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
[_myLayer addAnimation: animation forKey:@"transformAnimation"];
```

Comment: You know the timing function details (it's a simple bezier curve) so you could presumably work it out from there. Or you could cheat and use the freeze-frame ability of CAAnimation and just set your layer to a particular frame of the animation and see what the transform is. :)

Comment: Why do you want to know that? For fun or do you want to do something with those values?

Comment: I need to know it because I want to export an animation as a PNG sequence. Hence I want to set the values by hand (frame by frame) and export (render) the single frames.